# Anchor link is not working from JSON string in ionic 3 and angular 4 : ur "<a (click)='openActionPage()'>terms and conditions</a>"

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular4-forms

Am using this string in JSON file.

In order to proceed, you need to agree with our 
"terms and conditions" and adding for accessing in frontend using

```
<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message.content">    {{message.content}}</message>
```

but the link openActionPage() is not opening in front end.

Can anyone please suggest how me to solve this ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please consider a sample stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic

Comment: Am accessing that terms and conditions link from json to ionic templete, its not working

Comment: I think you'll get an error for some unsafe url. It would be clear if you could create a sample stackblitz project demoing this issue of yours

Comment: @webnav. I have changed some formatting in your question; but can you split yourself message so (if possible) horizontal scrollbar is not necessary. I don't know where to put new line. Can you repeat in first sentence what is THIS string that you are using ? Thanks. Can you wait that reviewer has accepted my change before making my request.

Comment: Now its coming in new line,

Answer (score 0):

so what you are trying to do here is to add dynamically some html code as innerHTML with anchor tag (a) and event binding to a method inside your ts file - this won't really work like this in Angular.

You think you could approach this differently and still show the "Accept T&C" button:

Firstly, remove a tag from your json completely just leave text content there.
Then make sure you have either interpolation ({{ }}) or attribute binding. Then do something like this:

```
<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message.content"></message>
<button *ngIf="message.termsAndConditions?">Accept T&C</button>
```

This will require adding a flag to your json file (if it is json), or if it is a string, do something like:

```
<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message.content"></message>
<button *ngIf="message.content.match('terms and conditions')">Accept T&C</button>
```

Based on your actual context there might be other ways to implement that, but in general I think doing "innerHTML" approach with events binding inside of the string content is not a great idea.

Comment: Am able to accept T&C, but once we click that "terms and conditions" link, am unable to open the model, Click event is not happening with this 

"In order to proceed, you need to agree with our <a (click)="OpenModal()">terms and conditions</a>.

Comment: can anyone help to achieve it.?

Comment: Hey, can you share your code and the json content? Its hard to help you further without full context of your code

Comment: ( “my.item1”: " Hi, In order to proceed, you need to agree with our <a (click)='openActionPage()>terms & conditions) - this my JSON string

using this (my.item1) key am accessing it in frontend from Mongo translations, please help me to proceed it


<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [innerHTML]="message.content">    {{message.content}}</message>
 this is my HTML code

Comment: Can you upload your code to stacklitz.com? Its impossible to help you without full code context